# Getting duplicate Firestore documents on Tableview (Swaft)

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting duplicate results even after emptying my array first can someone please explain why is this happening I have tried to empty this array `DriverOffers` in so many different places but still getting the same result duplicate tableView cells everywhere.

```
func newOrders(){

        //self.DriverOffers = [] here same result

        let fireStore = Firestore.firestore()
        let doc = fireStore.collection("الطلبات")
        
        doc.addSnapshotListener { (query, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print(err?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            }

            //self.DriverOffers = []

            query?.documentChanges.forEach({ (change) in
                
            //self.DriverOffers = []

                switch change.type{
                case .added:

               for document in query!.documents{
                        
                    self.DriverOffers = []

                    let snap = document.data()

                    let name = snap["name"] as? String ?? ""
                    let phone = snap["phone"] as? String ?? ""
                    let time = snap["time"] as? String ?? ""
                    let marketName = snap["marketName"] as? String ?? "موقع محدد"
                    let price = snap["amount"] as? String ?? ""

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    //self.DriverOffers = []

                    let offer = driverOrdersData(userUid: userid, name: name, phone: phone, amount: price)

                     self.DriverOffers.append(offer)
                     self.DriverOrdersTV.reloadData()
                                    
                  }
           }
}
                     case .removed:
                          print("removed")

                     case .modified:
                           break
                    
                }
            })
                    
        
    }
```

Comment: Is table view cell count is equal to array item count without duplicates?

Comment: yes it does `return DriverOffers.count`

Comment: Then check the prepareForReuse() method in table view cell.  Assign nil to all UI objects(nameLabel.text = nil)

Comment: can you show me some code please I didn't deal with `prepareForReuse()` before and surely don't know what are you saying

Answer (score 0):

Use this method inside the tableViewCell and check.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.nameLabel.text = nil
    }
```

Comment: that answer have nothing to do with what my code is